# Can AMP-HTML page have the same URL as the desktop version? Reponsive Design is used

Tags: amp-html

Can an Accelerated Mobile Pages have the same URL as the desktop version? We do already have responsive design by the way.

From what I have read all examples have the link rel="canonical" to its desktop version.

Answer (score 0):

> Can an Accelerated Mobile Pages have the same URL as the desktop version?

Yes. If you're building AMP-only website you [should](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/get_started/create/basic_markup) add `<link rel="canonical" href="http://path.to/your/amp/page">` to your AMP page's `<head>` that points to itself.

Note: you **should not** add `<link rel="amphtml">` tag to your `<head>` if you're building AMP-only website.